# How to develop a simple ASP.NET MVC project without Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been able to develop a simple asp.net project without vs. Can someone help me doing the same for a asp.net mvc 3. Starting from getting the ASP.NET MVC 3 framework. It seems that we can't download anymore the assemblies. Is it possible to have the project compiled on the fly ( I mean without compiling the my web application but letting IIS doing so , it is possible to achieve this with the regular asp.net so I assume it could be possible with the MVC framework)

Thx 
Dave

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sure, it's pretty easy, only a couple of steps after you install ASP.NET MVC 3.

1. Fire notepad.exe and create a `HomeController.cs` file (Of course if you don't want to use notepad you could also do this by using the [`copy con HomeController.cs`](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000398.htm) command on the command prompt, this way you will be closer to the metal):

   ```
   namespace MyApplication
   {
       using System.Web.Mvc;

       public class HomeController : Controller
       {
           public ActionResult Index()
           {
               return View();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Compile on the command prompt (adjust the folders to match yours)

   ```
   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /t:library /out:MyApplication.dll /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll" HomeController.cs
   ```
3. Create a folder `c:\MyApplication`
4. Create a folder `c:\MyApplication\bin` and copy `MyApplication.dll` to this `bin` folder.
5. Inside `c:\MyApplication\web.config`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <configuration>
     <appSettings>
       <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
       <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
       <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
     </appSettings>

     <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
         <assemblies>
           <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
           <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
           <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
           <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
           <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
         </assemblies>
       </compilation>

       <pages>
         <namespaces>
           <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
           <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
           <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
           <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
           <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
           <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
         </namespaces>
       </pages>
     </system.web>

     <system.webServer>
       <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
       <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
     </system.webServer>

   </configuration>
   ```
6. Inside `c:\MyApplication\Views\web.config`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>

   <configuration>
     <configSections>
       <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
         <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
         <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
       </sectionGroup>
     </configSections>

     <system.web.webPages.razor>
       <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
       <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
         <namespaces>
           <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
           <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
           <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
           <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
         </namespaces>
       </pages>
     </system.web.webPages.razor>

     <appSettings>
       <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
     </appSettings>

     <system.web>
       <httpHandlers>
         <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
       </httpHandlers>

       <pages
           validateRequest="false"
           pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
           pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
           userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
         <controls>
           <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
         </controls>
       </pages>
     </system.web>

     <system.webServer>
       <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

       <handlers>
         <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
         <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
       </handlers>
     </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```
7. Inside `c:\MyApplication\Global.asax`:

   ```
   <%@ Application Language="C#" %>
   <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mvc" %>
   <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
   <script runat="server">

   static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

       routes.MapRoute(
           "Default",
           "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
   }

   void Application_Start()
   {
       RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
   }
   </script>
   ```
8. Inside `c:\MyApplication\Views\Home\Index.cshtml`:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <title></title>
   </head>

   <body>
       Hello Word
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
9. Now you have all the necessary files for an ASP.NET MVC 3 application. The final step is to host it on a web server and run it.

---

Conclusion: unless you are suffering from some severe brain damage you will never do this and simply download [Visual Studio 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express) and start developping ASP.NET MVC 3 applications by following the tutorials on the [ASP.NET MVC web site](http://asp.net/mvc).

Comment: Brain damage. Teehehehe. I mean, you would also want to do this in case of emergency, you know, when your IDE is down or something. :)

Comment: @darin: seems to be what i want. Do you know how we can download the asp.net mvc 3 libs?

Comment: @Darin: Many thx, will have a look at your code but it seems staightforard to use and adapt.

Comment: but how do you run all these files? how do you start the web server?

Answer (score 2):

Could you give a reason you don't want to use visual studio?  There are free versions that are quite capable as IDEs.

If you would prefer to learn in a much more text editor experience you can also use [Microsoft WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) to create them on your local computer.

The easiest way to install Webmatrix or Visual Studio Web Developer Express is probably using the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx).

Comment: There is a little bit of i want to learn from the metal, it has always been my way to learn. Automated environment are for productivity but tend to hide the strengh of the underlying technologies. I have tried to install web express edition but it seems that it is a 30 days trial and wen need to register to some hotmail account  and i don't want to create one just for testing. These are the main reason.

Comment: I agree with Dave.  I learn better this way.  All this "built for you" stuff means I don't grasp the underlying concepts very quickly.

Comment: I also agree with Dave and Graham about the benefits of learning "from the ground up". Also, you may find yourself in an environment where Visual Studio isn't available and using the free version is not acceptable due to licensing/business restrictions.