# ASP.NET MVC3 in Visual Web Developer 2008 Express

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3

I've `Visual Web Developer 2008 Express` installed on my PC,

Does `ASP.NET MVC3` works in `visual web developer 2008 express`?

How to create simple `ASP.NET MVC3` site using simple text editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't work. ASP.NET MVC 3 requires .NET 4.0 and VS 2008 doesn't support .NET 4.0. You could use [Visual Studio 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express).

Comment: +1 Thanks for the info, I have .NET 4 installed, I just want to build a basic test site in mvc3, I've heard that we can edit the asp.net mvc code in simple text editor

Comment: @NitinJS, you cannot build an MVC3 site with VS2008. Yes, you can write an entire ASP.NET MVC 3 application using a text editor but that would be so much work that you shouldn't be doing it and instead you should download VS 2010. But if you want to be a masochist here's how to proceed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783378/how-to-develop-a-simple-asp-net-mvc-project-without-visual-studio/6783614#6783614

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Visual Studio 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express) alongside VS2008 - you do not need to uninstall VS2008, and it will not break your VS2008 configuration.

This will be your best option.