# How to generate deployment files for ASP.NET project without Visual Studio IDE?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, iis

I have developped an ASP.NET MVC5 application in visual studio 2013, and now evaluation version has expired.

I need to make a fiew changes on my source code and regenerate deployement files, is there a way to do it without IDE ?

I'm deploying it on IIS7 web server.

Comment: Community Edition is (generally) free - is that not an option?

Comment: I have developped all my application in Professional edition, there will not be any issue ?

Comment: Community Edition = Professional Edition, just with different licensing terms. If you can accept the Community Edition licensing, nothing should be different.

Comment: I'm using it in an entreprise it's Ok ?

Comment: Do you expect @Damien to read the license agreements for you? Are you going to hold him liable if he gets it wrong? [Here they are, read them yourself](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/dn877550.aspx). If your question actually is _"How to develop an ASP.NET MVC site without Visual Studio"_, that's way too broad. Start at compiling a console application using `csc`, then learn how to add referenced assemblies and so on. See also [How to develop a simple ASP.NET MVC project without Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783378/).

Comment: You can use the msbuild for the same. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393573.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can do it via visual studio command line(it should run after evaluation version expired)

```
msbuild C:\PathToYourSolution.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Test
```

Parameter "PublishProfile" is the name of xml file in folder YourWebProjectPath\Properties\PublishProfiles